# Changing from MYSQL to MYSQLI with localhost doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is perhaps a very silly mistake, however I am trying to change from mysql to mysqli.

I have the following setup in my **connection file**:

```
$hostname_DB = "localhost";
$database_DB = "dbname";
$username_DB = "username";
$password_DB = "*****";
$DB = mysqli_connect($hostname_DB, $username_DB, $password_DB, $database_DB ); 

$DB = new mysqli($hostname_DB, $username_DB, $password_DB, $database_DB );
if ($DB->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

In my index.php:

```
<?php $query_AcousticDB = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category = 'Acoustic ' ORDER BY RAND()";
$AcousticDB = mysqli_query($DB, $query_AcousticDB) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$row_AcousticDB = mysqli_fetch_assoc($AcousticDB);
$totalRows_AcousticDB = mysqli_num_rows($AcousticDB);?>
<!doctype html>
</body>
<div id="block2a_title"><?php echo $row_AcousticDB['Model']; ?><?php echo $row_AcousticDB['Color']; ?><?php echo $row_AcousticDB['Category']; ?></div>
<div id="block2a_image"><img src="<?php echo $filepath.$row_AcousticDB['LargeImage1']; ?>"></div>
<div id="block2a_RRP"><?php echo $row_AcousticDB['RRP']; ?></div>
<div id="block2a_Price"><?php echo $row_AcousticDB['AM_price']; ?></div>
</div>
</body
</html>
```

which displays everything fine when calling:
`localhost/index.php` however when you just type in `localhost` the data from the database is not displayed. When using th myqsl method it used to trigger all the data from the database when just typing in localhost.

Is there anything I am doing wrong. I am very sorry if this is something very obvious but I just can't see what I am doing wrong. Any help welcome.

Comment: You're mixing object oriented and procedural style. Pick one. You should use objected oriented style because procedural style is deprecated.

Comment: What's in directory of your webroot (localhost)? And try to remove your cache.

Comment: And pick the OOP style of programming.

Comment: Was there any problem using PDO for you ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com no just thought it would be easier to change from mysql to mysqli but im still undecided which one is better

Comment: Just changing to `i` wont work :)

Comment: Ha,ha found that out pretty quickly

Comment: @VeeeneX I have my website in there so I thought the index.php would be the start up page

Comment: I discovered what the problem was. There still was an index.html in the now I have removed it the index.php is the start up page. Thanks for all the suggestions I'll keep them in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In your code just remove the line below

```
$DB = new mysqli($hostname_DB, $username_DB, $password_DB, $database_DB );
```

and instead your code in connection file should look like below

```
$hostname_DB = "localhost";
$database_DB = "dbname";
$username_DB = "username";
$password_DB = "*****";
$DB = mysqli_connect($hostname_DB, $username_DB, $password_DB, $database_DB ) or die("Error : (".mysqli_error() ." )");
```

then you will be ok